# C# which pattern to use to have synchronous and pub/sub scenario for long-running task

Tags: c#, azure, design-patterns, architecture

Let's say I have an image processing library and I need it to work both ways - synchronously and as a pub/sub pattern. So the first method `ProcessBigListOfImages` doesn't return until it's done. And the second method `ProcessBigListOfImagesStart` should return instantaneously with some kind of subscription information (and better with a progress feedback), so it's invoked by that process somewhere down the road.

Now, this is what I need when use local file system and Azure compute and storage. Two different platforms but similar tasks. I want to have the same API. Is this doable?

I probably need to read again some books on design patterns just to refresh my memory...

Answer (score 0):

For long running tasks where you want to return instantly you will have to use queues (Azure services Bus / RabbitMQ etc). Just drop the message in queue with task Id and return your task ID that can be used to track.

On the other hand your worker process will pick up the task from queue and mark it complete against the task id. you can use db/cache service to save and track your task id. Your worker process really depends on your preference , it could be a web job, web server or serverless.

Comment: I know how to do it from a design point of view. I'm now sure how to make it nice and usable in C#. So my question was more about C# patterns.